# Cannot deploy Kubeflow on GCP: tells me to enable APIs that are already enabled

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

I am trying to install Kubeflow on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and Kubernetes Engine (GKE), following the [GCP deployment guide](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/).

I created a GCP project of which I am the owner, I enabled billing, set up OAuth credentials and enabled the following APIs:

- Compute Engine API
- Kubernetes Engine API
- Identity and Access Management (IAM) API
- Deployment Manager API
- Cloud Resource Manager API
- Cloud Filestore API
- AI Platform Training & Prediction API

However, when I want to [deploy Kubeflow using the UI](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-ui/), I get the following error:

[image]

So I doublechecked and those APIs are already enabled:

[image]

[image]

The log messages at the bottom of the screen are:

```
2020-03-0614:14:04.629: Getting enabled services for project <projectname>..
2020-03-0614:14:16.909: Could not configure communication with GCP, exiting
```

The [`Could not configure communication with GCP, exiting`](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L695) is triggered when [`_enableGcpServices()`](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L916) fails.

The line [`Getting enabled services for project ...`](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L922) is printed but not the line [`Proceeding with project number: ...`](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L944), so the error must be triggered somewhere in [the block of code between those lines](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L923-L942).

The call to [`Gapi.cloudresourcemanager.getProjectNumber(project)`](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L928-L929) has its own try/catch with a slightly different error message and title (only talks about the cloud resource manager API, not the IAM API), so I assume it is the call to [`Gapi.getSignedInEmail()`](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/gcp-click-to-deploy/src/DeployForm.tsx#L923) that fails??

Comment: Please review the permission in IAM of the user you are trying to deploy and make sure that this user has `Project Owner` permission. Please let me know.

Comment: @KoopaKiller Yes, I created the GCP project and have project owner permissions for the project.

Comment: This in fact might be in Kubeflow. However, I want to go back to square one: 1. Is this a private cluster? 2. Is this a paid GCP account?

Comment: @yyyyahir I have enabled billing for the account. I am not sure what you mean by "is it a private cluster"?

Comment: Just so it's useful for anyone facing this, googling the error message I found that the OP [reported it on Github](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4919) and found a [solution](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4919#issuecomment-609948945). Maybe @BioGeek want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at the service management API, IAM service credentials API and cloud identity aware proxy API possibly. I've only used the CLI install tool previously and not run into these problems, but you might require these services for the IAP deployment?

Comment: The first two APIs were already enabled. I also enabled the cloud identity aware proxy API, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was able to solve by correcting the project id.

Make sure that the project id on the UI form is specified correctly as it is on the GCP project - and that it does not have any leading or trailing spaces if you copy pasted from the GCP project details like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using in trial. Seems they allow a limited project to use billing account at same time. So I shut down unused ones . Went to Billing-->my projects. Disabled unused with 3 dots. Then tried to enable the billing account for current project. It worked.